# Determine which garbage collection (ART, Dalvik...) is used on my Android phone?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, dalvik

I am currently exploring garbage collection on Android. I want to know which garbage collection exactly (`ART` or `Dalvik` or whatever else) is used on my phone (`Pixel 2`, `Android 10`) so I can read up on how it works (e.g. if it uses a generational approach etc.) So, how can I find out which garbage collection my phone uses?

Answer (score 0):

ART has been the Android runtime on Android devices [since Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art).

Note that ART's GC algorithms get tweaked every so often, just as Dalvik's were.

Answer (score -1):

**What is Dalvik?**

Dalvik is a Just In Time (JIT) compiler. By the term JIT, we mean to say that whenever you run your app in your mobile device then that part of your code that is needed for execution of your app will only be compiled at that moment and rest of the code will be compiled in the future when needed.

**What is ART?**

ART or Android Runtime is an Android runtime that uses Ahead Of Time(AOT). By using AOT, what is does is it converts or compiles the whole High-level language code into Machine level code and at the time of installation of the app and not dynamically as the application runs(like in case of Dalvik).

**Conclusion**

Dalvik uses JIT and have a lot of drawbacks that were replaced by ART. So, from Android 4.4(Kitkat) ART was introduced as runtime and finally from Android 5.0(Lollipop), the Dalvik was completely replaced by ART by Android.

**About your phone**

`Pixel 2, Android 10` is above Android Version 5.0, so it is definitely using ART.